How to insert python/kivy input variable into MySQL database
I am having trouble getting a python/kivy varialbe input to load into my MySQL database. When I run the program, there is a kivy GUI input box that opens and asks the user to enter an id, email, and password.

After I enter the requested data, I want to be able to hit the "Submit" button and have those 3 input data fields be populated into my MySQL database into a table called Person. I have already established that Table and put 3 fields into it called "user_name", "email", and "password". There is also a 4th field that auto assigns an auto incremented key, but that is done automatically by MySQL. I know the "Submit" button works properly and I can even print out the inputed data.
The code I am using to have this data submitted into database is mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO Person(user_name, email, password) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)",({f"id"}, {f"email"}, {f"password"})). I get an error on this stating _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Python type set cannot be converted.
Here is the total code I have written:
import mysql.connector
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="root",
    database="testdatabase"
    )

mycursor=db.cursor()

class MyGridLayout(GridLayout):
    # Intialize infinite keywords
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        #Call grid layout contstructor
        super(MyGridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        #Set columns
        self.cols = 1

        #create second grid layout
        self.top_grid = GridLayout()
        self.top_grid.cols = 2

        #add widgets
        self.top_grid.add_widget(Label(text="Choose Your User ID: "))
        #add input box
        self.id = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.top_grid.add_widget(self.id)

        #add widgets
        self.top_grid.add_widget(Label(text="Enter a Valid Email Address: "))
        #add input box
        self.email = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.top_grid.add_widget(self.email)

        #add widgets
        self.top_grid.add_widget(Label(text="Choose a Strong Password: "))
        #add input box
        self.password = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.top_grid.add_widget(self.password)

        #add top grid to app
        self.add_widget(self.top_grid)

        #create submit button
        self.submit = Button(text="Submit", font_size=32,)
        #bind button
        self.submit.bind(on_press=self.press)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)


    def press(self, instance):
        id = self.id.text
        email = self.email.text
        password = self.password.text


        self.add_widget(Label(text=f"The User ID you entered is: {id} \nThe email you entered is: {email} \nThe password you entered is: {password}"))

        #clear the input boxes
        self.id.text = ""
        self.email.text = ""
        self.password.text = ""

mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO Person(user_name, email, password) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)",({f"id"}, {f"email"}, {f"password"}))


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGridLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()

Can somebody let me know what I am doing wrong here and point me to the solution of getting that variable input data to populate into my MySQL database.
